# Cauchy sequences and their importance

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, uniform-continuity

What are cauchy sequences? And why are they important?

Comment: A Cauchy sequence is a sequence of numbers such that $lim_{m,n\to\infty} a_n- a_m= 0$ where m and n go to infinity independently.  They are important because a sum $\sum_{i= 1}^\infty a_i$ converges if and only if $\{a_i\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.  ("m and n go to infinity independently" means we cannot assume any relationship between the two.  For example, if $a_n= \frac{1}{n}$ then **succeeding** terms, with n= m+ 1, satisfy $a_n- a_m= \frac{1}{m+1}- \frac{1}{m}= \frac{m}{m(m+1)}- \frac{m+ 1}{m(m+ 1)}= -\frac{1}{m(m+1)}$ goes to 0 but the series does not converge).

Comment: "$\sum_i a_i$ converges if and only if $\{a_i\}$ is a Cauchy sequence."  That is not true, take the standard example of $a_n=1/n$.